# finding the sum of the digits in a character array using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
int sum=0;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter number");
int y=sc.nextInt();
String s=String.valueOf(y);
char [] ch=s.toCharArray();

for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
{
    sum+=ch[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

If I input the number '111' i am getting 147! I want to get 3. I cant find the mistake.

I converted an integer to string to character array so that I can use it in a for loop. I know it is a silly mistake I have missed but cant find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original code you were summing the `int` values from casting the `char` values.  However, in your case you want to sum the actual numerical representations of those `char` values.  Change your `for` loop to this:

```
for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]);
}
```

Comment: Mistake:the sum and ch are two diff data types. Am i right?

Comment: I think that you are currently adding the ASCII value of each character instead of its numerical representation.

Answer (score 1):

That is because, when you assign a character type to integer, the JVM will assign the ASCII value rather than an int format of char as you expect.

Try something like parseInt...

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
{
    sum += Integer.parseInt(ch[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you calculate the `sum` of character values not integer values. You can convert each `char` digit to `int` by subtract the value of `'0'` from it:

```
for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
{
    sum=sum+(ch[i]-'0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
    sum += ch[i] - '0';
}
```

This solution offsets the ASCII integer values by the ASCII value for 0, thereby converting them to their actual numerical integer values.

Comment: This is a very nice alternative to the answer I gave.